# Can inline CSS apply to child elements nested in the styled element?

Tags: html, css

This is the problem in a nutshell:

- I want to apply the style `vertical-align: top` to every `<tr>` in a table, *without* manually applying the style to every row.
- I have to use inline CSS because I'm on a wiki, so I can't edit
  the external style sheet, or edit the `<head>` to embed a style.
- When I add a style attribute to a `<table>` tag, it appears this style is not passed on to its child elements. (I can see how this is nearly always a good thing.)
- I can't use `<style><!--...--></style>`, because that is not a permitted tag on MediaWiki pages.

**Should I resign myself to adding `style="vertical-align: top` to every `<tr>`, or is still a solution I am overlooking?**

EDIT: Removed a lump of background info, in order to limit the question to what the question title suggests it is about.

Comment: The question relates to MediaWiki pages in particular. You can't use inline javascript on MediaWiki pages either.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> Can inline CSS apply to child elements nested in the styled element?

Not directly.

Indirectly, only if the child element has `that-property: inherit` set in its existing stylesheet.

Answer (score 21):

I was interested in this question from a different context, specifically for styling html emails. Since css can't be added to the head of an email in gmail (believe it or not) the only way to consistently apply email styles is inline.

The answer to this question is no, there is no acceptable way to circumvent the problem in this or any other context that I'm aware of. When approaching a problem like this it is helpful to think about whether the style that you are trying to apply should be an "exception" or a "rule", i.e. if 90% of your tds are vertically-aligned top, you should just apply the style as a rule and go through and correct the 10%. When doing this it's important that you clearly specify your exceptions, preferably with a comment block that references the "rule".

For full reference on what css is supported and where this is very helpful: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score -5):

Im not familiar with Wiki's but can you create a class and apply a style to all child nodes in that class?

So ...

```
<style type="text/CSS"><!-- SomeClass tr { vertical-align: top } --></style>

<table class="SomeClass">

</table>
```

Worth a try?

Comment: D'oh. Turns out that `<style>` can perfectly well appear and work in the body of ordinary HTML pages, as you suggest. *But,* `<style>` is not a permitted tag in Mediawiki syntax, and that was my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I have a MediaWiki page on which I have a large table, and I need to center the text in the second column. If I could use the <style> tag, it would be easy to create the rule `mediawiki.table td:nth-child(2) { text-align:center; }` but otherwise I have no idea what I can do. Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score -12):

Use following :

```
<style type="text/css">

table tr td {
   vertical-align:top;
}

</style>
```

Comment: the question explicitly refers to inline styles.