# Applying inline css to the element child

Tags: html, css

In the following markup, the `ul` has a color set as style. I want to apply that color to only the `<i>` inside the `li` items, but do not want to apply that color to the text outside the `<i>`, without changing the markup?

PS. I'm not able to use css classes because the color is dynamically picked.

```
<ul style="color: #ff3300">
    <li><i>colored</i> normal text</li>
    <li><i>colored</i> normal text</li>
</ul>
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/uzVVG/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833075/can-inline-css-apply-to-child-elements-nested-in-the-styled-element

Comment: How is it possible without changing the markup and with no CSS ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the color is dynamically picked"? Who picks it, when?

Comment: Since, as you say, "the color is dynamically picked", why not just use jQuery to apply the color change directly to the child elements: `$("ul li i").css("color", "#ff3300");` I can't see another way of the color being "dynamically picked" that does not involve some form of JS.

Answer (score 1):

make use of span....

```
<li><i><span style="color:Red">Colored</span></i> normal text</li>
```